# Executing hive QL statements on one table for all rows of a column of another table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have one Hive table (lets say, A) that has two columns namely sessionId and status. I need to run a set of HiveQL queries on another table (Let's say B) for all the sessionIds in table A. There are several columns in table B out of which one column is sessionId. This B.sessionId will be compared against A.sessionId while extracting a row. I am trying to achieve something like below

```
for all sessionIds in Table A 
BEGIN
  select a, b,c from {
     case when B.data < 50 then B.data end as a,
     case when B.num < 100 then B.num end as b,
     case when B.air < 150 then B.air end as c     
     } 
END
```

Is it possible to achive the above? Can someone give me an idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Join instead of case statement?

```
select t2.data,t2.num,t2.air
from tableA t1,tableB t2
where t1.sessionid = t2.sessionid
and t2.data < 50
and t2.num < 100
and t2.air < 150;
```

Assuming following is the table structure

```
create table tableA
(sessionid int,
status string);

create table tableB
(sessionid int,
data int,
num int,
air int
);
```